# Android button slow action

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity, sdk

I have a button that leads to another page. And whenever I click it I get this info code in logcat :

```
12-07 16:09:45.073: I/ActivityManager(273): Displayed com.example.prva/.button: +1s764ms
```

Seconds and ms vary of course each time between 1-3 seconds. The problem is that I noticed that it takes a while for that button to open that page. It has some kind of pause or whatever and this is the only relevant thing I have found in the logcat that could be connected to it. How can I fix this, why is this button acting "slow"?

This is where the button code is :

```
   package com.example.prva;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Meni_Splash extends Activity{  


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

        Button btnv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonv);
        btnv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(Meni_Splash.this, button.class));              
            }
        });         
    }
}
```

And this is the class that opens :

```
package com.example.prva;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

public class button extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.button);

        //Button click sound
        final MediaPlayer MPRadio1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.radio1);
        final MediaPlayer MPRadio2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.radio2);
        final MediaPlayer MPRadio3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.radio3);

        final RadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3;        

        rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        rb3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio3);


        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonplay);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
                if(rb1.isChecked())
                {
                MPRadio1.start();
                }
            else
                {
                if(rb2.isChecked())
                {
                    MPRadio2.start();
                }
                    else
                    {
                        if(rb3.isChecked())
                        {
                        MPRadio3.start();
                    }
                }   
                }
            }
        }

    );}}
```

I don't know what thing could make it so slow from these activities?

Comment: Maybe it's something in the other activity that's doing so long to open it. In the onCreate or onResume method?

Comment: Do you try it on emulator? If so try on device.

Comment: Like @Tooroop says, it is most likely that your `Meni_Splash` Takes a long time to intialise.

Comment: Try to run this code in different thread.

Comment: your activity is too slow.

Comment: @Tooroop I have updated my post and posted the whole classes. Can you see what makes it slow from there?

Comment: @user1880779 Java class naming conventions strongly recommend uppercase letters to start. You should probably refactor your `button` class to `Button`, I'd even throw my first initial in front so as to avoid using keywords. i.e. `JButton`. Though I doubt this is your issue.

Comment: @Asok thank for the tip! But yeah, unfortunately that doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: @Doomsknight How can I prevent that long initialise time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks pretty decent to be honest. Not sure entirely what could be causing it to intialise slowly.

But there are two areas to look at.

The first, most likely, is your layout loading:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.button);
```

I dont imagine your layout to be complex though. But if it is, aka, lots of nested views (linear layouts within other linear layouts), or lots of views (textviews etc) in general on the page, then it could be taking a while to "inflate" the Layout.

Alternatively and less likely, is that MediaPlayer.create takes a fair while to load. The reason I suggest this, is I have no idea how it works, as I've not used it before.

```
    //Button click sound
    final MediaPlayer MPRadio1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.radio1);
    final MediaPlayer MPRadio2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.radio2);
    final MediaPlayer MPRadio3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.radio3);
```

The best thing to do, would be to profile it with the DDMS profiler. Or put a timer around it, and print the results to logcat.

Also, on a quick note, is it just 2-3 seconds loading? And is it really that bad for what its trying to do?

Comment: Unfortunately button.xml has only 3 little radio buttons and a normal button. All my layouts are just a background color and a button or two. Nothing fancy. So that can't be a problem. This code you've posted (MediaPlayer) is just linking a sound to the media player. Its not very bad but the whole app doesn't seem smooth if you know what I mean. It seems a little bit buggy and slow with all those little pauses which happen quite often (mostly when clicking a button which creates a new activity). Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user1880779 Yea sorry Im not much help. Not sure what else it could be code wise. Possibly, its just a device limitiation. Have you tried moving screen to screen on other apps? Do they response with a delay too?

Comment: I'll try and test it on other device. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hey, I have the same problem, but I have many layouts within layouts. It may be taking time to inflate, as you said. How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Take a look at this official guide on [improving layout performance](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/index.html)